# How to append to a JSON file in Python?

Tags: python, json

I have the a JSON file which contains `{"67790": {"1": {"kwh": 319.4}}}`. Now I create a dictionary `a_dict` which I need to append to the JSON file.

I tried this code:

```
with open(DATA_FILENAME, 'a') as f:
   json_obj = json.dump(a_dict, json.load(f)
   f.write(json_obj)
   f.close()
```

What is wrong with the code? How can I fix the problem?

Comment: You don't need to do `f.close()` when you use `with open(...) as f:`

Comment: What is `append` supposed to mean here? For example, what is in `a_dict` beforehand, and **what should the result be**?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Assuming you have a `test.json` file with the following content:

```
{"67790": {"1": {"kwh": 319.4}}}
```

Then, the code below will `load` the json file, update the data inside using `dict.update()` and `dump` into the `test.json` file:

```
import json

a_dict = {'new_key': 'new_value'}

with open('test.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

data.update(a_dict)

with open('test.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
```

Then, in `test.json`, you'll have:

```
{"new_key": "new_value", "67790": {"1": {"kwh": 319.4}}}
```

Hope this is what you wanted.

Comment: What if we wanted to do this ? {"67790": {"1": {"kwh": 319.4,"new_key": "new_value", }}}

Comment: The problem is that using the "w" option it rewrites the file every single time you want to change or add to json file.

Comment: How to append add elements to an already existing array inside the JSON?

Comment: to append use `data["key"].append({"new_key":"new_value"})`

Comment: How is `data.update(a_dict)` not out of scope or boundary. @alexce

Comment: @AST a python dict doesn't have a fixed length. The update function will update existing entries or create them if not existing yet. However does anyone knows how to append to a json file without rewriting the whole file and possibly destroy it's indentation?

Answer (score 4):

You need to update the output of json.load with a_dict and then dump the result.
And you cannot append to the file but you need to overwrite it.

Answer (score -4):

```
json_obj=json.dumps(a_dict, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Comment: Won't this just overwrite the object?

Comment: It will overwrite the json file with this `a_dict` object unless you updates `a_dict` with all values which you want to store.