# update the serializer with a new dict

Tags: django

I have created a simple service which returns the data from a single table based on a param in the URL as follow:
I would like to append to the JSON list another object as:

```
{
"execution_time": "13:00"
}
```

so the result can be:

```
[
    {
    "figonr": "1078924300-01",
    "description": "F150/C+W/CC/GE201S/S/OE/SE",
    "productgroup": null
    },
    {
    "execution_time": "13:00"
    }
]
```

How can I add the above object to the JSON list of objects?
thanks

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/figo?figonr=1078924300-01
output is the json:
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

[
   {
        "figonr": "1078924300-01",
        "description": "F150/C+W/CC/GE201S/S/OE/SE",
        "productgroup": null
   }
]
```

my View is as folowing:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

 # Create your views here.

 from rest_framework import generics
 from servicesapp.models import Figo
 from servicesapp.serializers import ServiceAppSerializer


  class ListCreateFigos(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
        serializer_class = ServiceAppSerializer

        http_method_names = ['get']

        def get_queryset(self):
             queryset = None
             figo_nr = self.request.query_params.get('figonr', None)
             if figo_nr is not None:
                   queryset = Figo.objects.filter(figonr = figo_nr)
             return queryset
```

and serializer:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from servicesapp.models import Figo
import datetime

class ServiceAppSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     class Meta:
          model = Figo
          fields=('__all__')
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18980132/5739514

Comment: but I do not know how to get the json object in Django