# Storing responses as files using Scrapy Splash

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-splash, splash-js-render

I'm creating my first scrapy project with Splash and work with the testdata from http://quotes.toscrape.com/js/
I want to store the quotes of each page as a separate file on disk (in the code below I first try to store the entire page). I have the code below, which worked when I was not using `SplashRequest`, but with the new code below, nothing is stored on disk now when I 'Run and debug' this code in Visual Studio Code.
Also `self.log` does not write to my Visual Code Terminal window. I'm new to Splash, so I'm sure I'm missing something, but what?

Already checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24735264/how-to-store-response-in-scrapy) and [here](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash).

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest

class QuoteItem(scrapy.Item):
    author = scrapy.Field()
    quote = scrapy.Field()   

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "jsscraper"

    
    start_urls = ["http://quotes.toscrape.com/js/"]

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield SplashRequest(url=url, callback=self.parse, endpoint='render.html')

    def parse(self, response):
        for q in response.css("div.quote"):            
            quote = QuoteItem()
            quote["author"] = q.css(".author::text").extract_first()
            quote["quote"] = q.css(".text::text").extract_first()
            yield quote

        #cycle through all available pages
        for a in response.css('ul.pager a'):
            yield SplashRequest(url=a,callback=self.parse,endpoint='render.html',args={ 'wait': 0.5 })

       
        page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        filename = 'quotes-%s.html' % page
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
        self.log('Saved file %s' % filename)
```

**UPDATE 1**

How I debug it:

- In Visutal Studio Code, hit F5
- Select 'Python file'

Output tab is empty

Terminal tab contains:

```
PS C:\scrapy\tutorial>  cd 'c:\scrapy\tutorial'; & 'C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe' 'c:\Users\Mark\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.9.114305\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\launcher' '58582' '--' 'c:\scrapy\tutorial\spiders\quotes_spider_js.py'
PS C:\scrapy\tutorial>
```

Also, nothing is logged in my Docker container instance, which I thought was required for Splash to work in the first place.

**UPDATE 2**

I ran `scrapy crawl jsscraper` and a file 'quotes-js.html' is stored on disk. However, it contains the page source HTML without any JavaScript code executed. I'm looking to execute the JS code on 'http://quotes.toscrape.com/js/' and store only the quote content. How can I do so?

Comment: I get "Saved file" log output and the file is saved when testing. You should share the full output log you get when running scrapy.

Comment: Haven't used VSCode recently so I might be reading that incorrectly, but it looks to me like it's just running your code using the `python` executable. This code needs to be executed using the `scrapy` command (e.g. `scrapy crawl` or `scrapy runspider`)

Comment: Thanks again :-), please see my update 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**WRITING OUTPUT TO A JSON FILE:**

I have tried to solve your problem. Here is the working version of your code. I hope this is what you are trying to achieve.

```
import json

import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest


class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "jsscraper"

    start_urls = ["http://quotes.toscrape.com/js/page/"+str(i+1) for i in range(10)]

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield SplashRequest(
                url=url,
                callback=self.parse,
                endpoint='render.html',
                args={'wait': 0.5}
            )

    def parse(self, response):
        quotes = {"quotes": []}
        for q in response.css("div.quote"):
            quote = dict()
            quote["author"] = q.css(".author::text").extract_first()
            quote["quote"] = q.css(".text::text").extract_first()
            quotes["quotes"].append(quote)

        page = response.url[response.url.index("page/")+5:]
        print("page=", page)
        filename = 'quotes-%s.json' % page
        with open(filename, 'w') as outfile:
            outfile.write(json.dumps(quotes, indent=4, separators=(',', ":")))
```

**UPDATE:**
Above code has been updated to scrape from all pages and save results in separate json files from page-1 to 10.

This will write the list of quotes from each page to a separate json file as following:

```
{
    "quotes":[
        {
            "author":"Albert Einstein",
            "quote":"\u201cThe world as we have created it is a process of our thinking. It cannot be changed without changing our thinking.\u201d"
        },
        {
            "author":"J.K. Rowling",
            "quote":"\u201cIt is our choices, Harry, that show what we truly are, far more than our abilities.\u201d"
        },
        {
            "author":"Albert Einstein",
            "quote":"\u201cThere are only two ways to live your life. One is as though nothing is a miracle. The other is as though everything is a miracle.\u201d"
        },
        {
            "author":"Jane Austen",
            "quote":"\u201cThe person, be it gentleman or lady, who has not pleasure in a good novel, must be intolerably stupid.\u201d"
        },
        {
            "author":"Marilyn Monroe",
            "quote":"\u201cImperfection is beauty, madness is genius and it's better to be absolutely ridiculous than absolutely boring.\u201d"
        },
        {
            "author":"Albert Einstein",
            "quote":"\u201cTry not to become a man of success. Rather become a man of value.\u201d"
        },
        {
            "author":"Andr\u00e9 Gide",
            "quote":"\u201cIt is better to be hated for what you are than to be loved for what you are not.\u201d"
        },
        {
            "author":"Thomas A. Edison",
            "quote":"\u201cI have not failed. I've just found 10,000 ways that won't work.\u201d"
        },
        {
            "author":"Eleanor Roosevelt",
            "quote":"\u201cA woman is like a tea bag; you never know how strong it is until it's in hot water.\u201d"
        },
        {
            "author":"Steve Martin",
            "quote":"\u201cA day without sunshine is like, you know, night.\u201d"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: it does! Can you help with 1 last thing: make sure it collects the quotes from all the pages? That part does not seem to work now. Once that's done, the bounty is yours :)

Comment: I gave you the 150 bounty, would appreciate it very much if you could help out with my last question, I've updated my original post with what I tried, see block `#cycle through all available pages`. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much. Sure, I will try that part and get back to you soon.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Now it scrapes all available pages and stores results from each page into a separate json file.

Comment: Hi Arslan, thanks again! This code is however very hardcoded, how would it be possible to detect the number of available pages rather than explicitly stating "10"? E.g. by detecting the presence of the "Next" button in the paging element?

Comment: Yes. Alternatively, at the end of your parse function, you can request next page by following the link under the next button  and then passing the same parse function in the callback.

Comment: Should've posted my attempt right away :S, but this is what I placed at the end of the parse function and what does not seem to cycle through the pages:
`for a in response.css('ul.pager a'):
 yield SplashRequest(url=a,callback=self.parse,endpoint='render.html',args={ 'wait': 0.5 })`

Comment: That's because the url under next button is relative. Put this code at the end of parse function.

`next_page = response.xpath(".//nav/ul/li[@class='next']/a/@href").get()
        if next_page:
            yield SplashRequest(
                url="http://quotes.toscrape.com"+next_page,
                callback=self.parse,
                endpoint='render.html',
                args={'wait': 0.5}
            )
`
 
 P.S. I had to hardcode the base url part bcz I couldn't find a better solution. There must be some better way to get the base url of the request.

Comment: Awesome, that works. One last question: what if I want all results in a single file instead of separate files? I tried moving the initializing `quotes = {"quotes": []}` outside of the `parse` function, but that throws a design time error.

Comment: For that, you will have to append in the same file instead of writing in a separate file each time. Define a file name and append the results in the same file each time. Please refer to question: 18980039 (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18980039/how-to-append-in-a-json-file-in-python)

Comment: Hi Arslan, the storing in a single file I should hopefully be able to figure out myself, my question was more on how I can maintain a variable outside of the scope of the `def parse` function to keep appending the individual `quote` dict results to. I tried moving `quotes = {"quotes": []}` outside of `def parse` but that throws an error.

Comment: If you want to move it outside, then declare it as class attribute just like `name` and `start_urls`
Then refer to it inside the parse function with `self` keyword i.e. `self.quotes`

Answer (score 1):

## Problem

JavaScript on website you wish to scrape isn’t being executed.

## Solution

Increase `ScrappyRequest` wait time to allow JavaScript to execute.

### Example

```
yield SplashRequest(
    url=url,
    callback=self.parse,
    endpoint='render.html',
    args={ 'wait': 0.5 }
)
```

Comment: Thanks. This code however throws a syntax error: "positional argument follows keyword argument" on the single quote before `wait` command

Comment: @Flo updated my answer. Based on https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash Usage -> Requests

Comment: thanks 1 step further as that indeed works :) But it stores the full page now and not just the quotes, how can I make sure only the quotes are stored (preferably as XML items)?

Comment: @Flo the DOM is probably a bit different than before so you need to ensure that you’re parsing the DOM correctly—or you need to increase wait time to be longer if JavaScript hasn’t finished processing.

Comment: the wait time is good, as the DOM is full rendered. And I'm using CSS selector `div.quote`, which is exactly what's in the rendered HTML. I'm just not sure how to use the result from `yield quote` and save those results as XML in the file...

Comment: @Flo I'll run it locally later tonight and get back to you.