# Append to a json file in python

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to append elements to a json file

```
import json
person = {
    "fname": "Chris",
    "lname": "Morten",
    "age": "25"
    }
with open("guest.json", "a") as file:
    json.dump(person, file, indent=3, ensure_ascii=False)
```

I want to add person varible just once

**and input from user in the same file **

```
f_name = input("What is your name? ")
l_name = input("What is your last name? ")
age = input("How old are you? ")
x = []
x.append({
    "fname": f_name,
    "lname": l_name,
    "age": age
})

with open("guest.json", "a") as file:
    json.dump(x, file, indent=3)
```

Every time i run the program person dictionary variable added again and the result will be like this:

```
{
   "fname": "Chris",
   "lname": "Morten",
   "age": "25"
}[
   {
      "fname": "nour",
      "lname": "ash",
      "age": "20"
   }
]{
   "fname": "Chris",
   "lname": "Morten",
   "age": "25"
}[
   {
      "fname": "nori",
      "lname": "sori",
      "age": "33"
   }
]
```

Can some one help me?

Comment: _Write_ to the file. Don't append. `json.dump()` dumps the _entire_ dictionary serialized as json.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to append in a json file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18980039/how-to-append-in-a-json-file-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 is to *read* the old json file. Remember to make an empty list if the file doesn't exist.

```
if <file exists>:
    with open("guest.json", "r") as jsonfile:
        guests = json.load(jsonfile)
else:
    guests = [] # no guests. make an empty list
```

Then, append new guests to what you already read.

```
f_name = input("What is your name? ")
l_name = input("What is your last name? ")
age = input("How old are you? ")

guests.append({
    "fname": f_name,
    "lname": l_name,
    "age": age
})
```

Finally, *write* this entire list to the file. *Don't append* -- `json.dump` will dump the *entire* serialilzed list into the file, including your old guests.

```
with open("guest.json", "w") as jsonfile:
        guests = json.dump(guests, jsonfile)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may always have a `list` in your file, that is populated with `dict` representing one person. You want to add element to your list, not the file itself directly

So you may

- read the file is exists to load previous list, or get a fresh one
- add your person to that list
- dump the file using mode `w` as you want to overwrite all

```
def main(filename):
    content = []
    if exists(filename):
        with open(filename) as file:
            content = json.load(file)

    f_name = input("What is your name? ")
    l_name = input("What is your last name? ")
    age = input("How old are you? ")

    content.append({"fname": f_name, "lname": l_name, "age": age})

    with open("guest.json", "w") as file:
        json.dump(content, file, indent=4)

main("guest.json")
```