# How to write a new dictionary to a json file

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have this function to make dictionaries into *json* objects and writes them to a *json* file:

```
def somethin(a1,a2,a3):
  
    someDict = {"a": a1,
                "b": a2,
                "c": a3
                }
   
    json_obj = json.dumps(someDict)
    file = open('somefile.json', 'a',encoding="utf-8")
    file.write(json_obj)
```

the first written element to the file doesnt present any problem, but after adding the second json object to the file I get: ***SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data*** with the json file I made:

```
{
    "a": 1,
    "b":2,
    "c": 3
}
{
    "a1": 1,
    "b1":2,
    "c1": 3
}
```

How can I modify the code for the json output file to be correct?

Comment: You can't have multiple objects in one json file. Either create separate files or combine dictionaries in a list first.

Comment: You can read the old JSON into memory as a dict, manipulate the dict as normal to add the new keys, then write it back out to disk. See [How to append in a json file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18980039/how-to-append-in-a-json-file-in-python). If you want a list of dicts, then use that structure in Python, the procedure is still the same for updating the file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few issues here:

```
file = open('somefile.json', 'a',encoding="utf-8")
```

You're implicitly assuming that the file will be closed here. That is true on CPython, but not on all Python implementations. A better approach would be:

```
with open('somefile.json', 'a',encoding="utf-8") as file:
    file.write(json_obj)
```

Because that uses a [context manager](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html) to explicitly close the file.

Second, you can avoid creating an extra string by writing directly to the file:

```
with open('somefile.json', 'a',encoding="utf-8") as file:
    json.dump(someDict, file)
```

Third, having multiple JSON objects in a file is not valid JSON. There are a few approaches you could take here. One is to wrap the JSON objects in a list:

```
[
{
    "a": 1,
    "b":2,
    "c": 3
},
{
    "a1": 1,
    "b1":2,
    "c1": 3
}
]
```

So, start the file with an open bracket, and write a comma after every JSON object, except the last one, then end the file with a close bracket.

Second approach would be to newline-separate your JSON objects, like this:

```
{"a": 1,"b":2,"c": 3}
{"a1": 1, "b1":2,"c1": 3}
```

Each line is a JSON object. You'd read this like so:

```
with open("filename", "rt") as file:
    for line in file:
        obj = json.loads(line)
        # do something with obj
        # ...
```

The advantage of this approach would be that you can now load each individual JSON object in memory, without having to load the entire file in at once. The disadvantage is that you're no longer writing valid JSON, so you can't use tools like `jq` on the output. (If you want the best of both worlds, you can use a package like ijson, but that's more complex.)

Comment: for the array wrap solution, how could I implement something like that?
I tried having a file with only "[" and writing "," after each obj write, but the problem I get is that at the end I will have something like ",]" that brakes the json.

Comment: @AMM Two approaches you could use. 1) Have a parameter to your append function which tells it "this is the last object." The calling code would have the responsibility of determining when the last object is. OR 2) have a global variable signifying whether this is the *first* object. If it's the first, you write `object`. If it's not the first, write `,object`. You still put commas between objects, but it's now appended before each object instead of after each object.